# SQL: using DATEPART and Inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, datepart

I'm getting myself familiar with DATEPART and in this case the week part, to get results per week and so on.

I got it to work with this following query.

```
var querytest = "SELECT DATEPART(wk, date), sum((kg * rep * sett)) as weight, 
sum(kg / max * rep * sett) as avg, sum((rep * sett)) as reps 
FROM Test WHERE date between @0 and @1 AND exercise < 4 GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, date)";
```

However that doesn't really do everything that I want, I also couldn't add date into that query as it gave me error. Like this `...sum((rep * sett)) as reps, date FROM`

```
                                                 ^
```

date like the above. It gave me errors about something with the grouping at the end.

But I want to use datepart(wk) in the following query, any idea how to do this?
(using SQL Server Compact!)

```
var querythiss = "SELECT DATEPART(wk, date), SUM(kg * rep * sett) as weight, SUM(kg / max * rep * sett) as avg, SUM(rep * sett) as reps, " +
                " t.date, pk.peak FROM Test t INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(kg / max) as peak, date FROM Test WHERE date BETWEEN @0 AND " +
                " @1 AND exercise < 4 group by date) as pk on t.date = pk.date WHERE t.date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4 GROUP " +
                "BY t.date, pk.peak";
```

Or like this if this is easier to read.

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk, date),
    SUM(kg * rep * sett) as weight, 
    SUM(kg / max * rep * sett) as avg,   
    SUM(rep * sett) as reps,
    t.date, pk.peak 
FROM Test t INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(kg / max) as peak, date 
    FROM Test 
    WHERE date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 
    AND exercise < 4 
    GROUP BY date
) as pk on t.date = pk.date 
WHERE t.date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY t.date, pk.peak
```

Comment: Could you add the error message?

Comment: In the final query, that want to get working, _what is the error_ please post the entire error, not a vague recollection of it

Comment: Syntax: alias is needed `DATEPART(wk, t.date)` otherwise date is ambiguous.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid @McNets well, Without the datepart stuff the query works, but when I add `DATEPART(wk, date)` in the beginning and in the `GROUP BY` it gives me this error `The column name cannot be resolved to a table. Specify the table to which the column belongs. [ Name of ambiguous column = date ]`

Comment: try `DATEPART(wk, t.date)`

Comment: Well, @Serg is correct.

Comment: @Serg that did remove the error, however it didnt show the total by week for some reason, does it have anything to do with `WHERE date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4 GROUP BY date` this part of the code?

Comment: @PontusSvedberg do you need the date on the `select`? I would suggest you remove it and only show the week, then group by week

Comment: @Stephen Well, maybe not but maybe the number of the week then? I want to use this data in a Google chart api, so date will be the vertical axis, however now when I think about it, week number would be better since its a weekly sum anyway

Comment: @PontusSvedberg as long as you are working on week level, it should be fine, immediately you group by `date` then you are no longer working on weeks but on `datetime`, which is not the desired outcome

Comment: Ye I realized it didn't really make sense haha, I'll see if I can make it work by removing the date part!

Comment: @Stephen would you mind helping out with removing the date stuff that should not be there, I'm confused with all this since its the first time Im using joins and stuff, i've tried to remove some here and there but didnt succeed haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be similar to this: of course without sample data it's difficult to test, but you can tweak as required.

```
SELECT pk.dateWeek,
    SUM(kg * rep * sett) as weight, 
    SUM(kg / max * rep * sett) as avg,   
    SUM(rep * sett) as reps,
    pk.peak 
FROM Test t 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(kg / max) as peak, DATEPART(wk, date) as dateWeek 
    FROM Test 
    WHERE date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 
    AND exercise < 4 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, date)
) as pk on  DATEPART(wk, t.date) = pk.dateWeek 
WHERE date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 
AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY  pk.dateWeek, pk.peak
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide all the info you need from the first query without the need of a inner join since you are requesting from the same table. Something like the following query should work for a weekly data return.

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk, date) as wknumber, sum((kg * rep * sett)) as weight, 
sum(kg / max * rep * sett) as avg, sum((rep * sett)) as reps,
max(kg / max) as peak
FROM Test WHERE date between @0 and @1 AND exercise < 4 GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, date)
```

Comment: resulted in this, `In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions. [ Select clause = ,date ]`, I dont know much about this, but when I got this query working from the very beginning, without the datepart stuff, the need for the inner join was because I couldn't combine MAX(..) with SUM(..) because MAX would only give one result and SUM would give more results because there are sometimes more than one row in the database with the same date!

Comment: The problem was that i have to group by the expression and not the alias, I will edit it with the correct query. Also, since sum and max are both aggregate operands they could both work together.

Comment: wow, thats really cool! Perhaps my earlier problem was due to me grouping by date when I did not use datepart, or does it still work with both max and sum then?

Comment: the second query you posted has the problem that you werent groping by the "datepart(wk,date)", so this results in a two different count results. Also in the second query you were grouping by day, not for week, as you requested. The most important thing when you are using groping oppperands is that the number of results for each variable you want to return must be the same, using a groping operand such as max, count, min... or by grouping it in the "group by clause". Sorry for my english if you don't understand something, it isn't my first language.